# How to open Excel sheet write protected?

Tags: excel

I have Matlab code using xlswrite to save data to an excel sheet.

Can I open Excel such that Matlab will still be able to write? Also, can I refresh silently?

(In Notepad++ this would be realized via Preferences > MISC > Update Silently, very useful for logfiles)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any way to achieve your 'Refresh Silently' functionality.

Of course, you can open an Excel file read-only easily using VBA or via the File Open dialog.